# Add dynamic hidden property on componentRef in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'v been using angular for quite a while now but I've recently switched to Angular 2. I'm trying to create a component programmatically and apply a hidden attribute so it can dynamically switch display state like:

```ts
<my-component [hidden]="imIHidden"></my-component>
```

I'm creating my component like so:

```ts
const component = this.moduleFactory.getComponent(this.componentFactoryResolver, MyComponent);
var componentRef = this.target.createComponent(component);
```

I've tried a couple of things but I can't get to set a hidden attribute on my newly created component. Can you please help me with this one?

Comment: `<my-component ...>` doesn't look like a dynamically created component. You can't use any bindings with dynamically added components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```ts
class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('hidden')
  isHidden: boolean = false;
}
```

```ts
componentRef.instance.isHidden = true;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked exactly like you said.